# What is the percentage of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, percentage

I need help determining the percent chance an item has to be picked by my algorithm. Essentially I created a hashmap of different items and then added an integer as the value to make some items less likely to appear. The way my algorithm works is by generating a random number between 0 and the size of the map. Then it will roll another random number between 1 and that chosen items assigned value. If that value matches the rolled number it will be added to an array. Also keep in mind this algorithm chooses 3 items out of the map and all 3 must be different so what is the percent chance each item will be chosen? Obviously you would need to know how many items there are and the associated values with each item but I can do that on my own I just want to know a general process for finding these percent's. Also after I figure out the percent each item has of showing up in the final set of 3 items I also need to take into account that those 3 items only have a 40% chance of showing up at all.

The first step is to figure out the percent chance each item has of showing up in the final 3 and the last step is to determine the chance those final 3 items have of showing up at all. I was thinking I could divide 3 by the maps total size (for example 20) which would give me a 15% chance of landing on each item before taking into account their assigned values in the map but where do I go from there because I am kind of getting lost with all these different things I need to take into account.

Comment: I think we need to see code, or at least pseudocode, for the algorithm.

Comment: If I understand the process correctly, what you're doing is randomly choose one-of-N items, and then give that item a one-in-V chance of being selected into the top 3. That's equivalent to assigning a weight to each item, and selecting an item using the weighted probability. The weight for an item is the least-common-multiple of all the values divided by the value for the item. For example, if the item values are {1,2,3,4,5}, then the item weights are {60,30,20,15,12}. Using weights is easier to analyze mathematically, and results in faster code (especially if the values are large).

Comment: How did u get those weights? Also your understanding of what I am asking is correct although it was only addressing a small portion of the question.

Comment: First compute the least-common-multiple (LCM) of the values, then for each item the weight is LCM / value. For example, if you have 10 items with values {1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5}, then the LCM of the values is 60 (all the values divide evenly into 60). Then convert values into weights with the formula `W = LCM / V`. So the weights are {60,30,30,20,20,20,15,15,12,12}

Comment: What do the weight stand for because it would make no sense for items with the lowest values to also have the largest weights. I think I just dont understand what you are trying to accomplish with these eight since they dont add up to 100%.

Comment: Items with the lowest values are the most likely to be chosen. Conversely, items with the highest values are least likely to be chosen. So the odds of an item being chosen are inversely proportional to its value. If you don't agree with that, then one of us doesn't understand the selection process correctly. With the weights, higher weight corresponds to increased probability of being selected.

Comment: To use the weights, first compute the sum of the weights. Then generate a random number between 0 and the `sum - 1` inclusive. If the random number is between 0 and 59, the first item is chosen. If the random number is between 60 and 89, the second item is chosen. And so on... After choosing one item, you remove it from the list and reduce the `sum` by its weight. Then choose the second and third items using the same method, but with the reduced `sum` and shorter list.